# button stops working in javafx when text is out of pane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently working on a project for school using javafx. This class gets "name" and "btUp and "btDown" from class bottomPane. The Text "name" is displayed on the screen and when btnUp is hit the text moves up. The text will move up and off the screen like I want it to, but when I hit "btnDown" the text just moves down until it is inside of the bottomPane and freezes. Any help would be appreciated. All of these panes are inside a GridPane and the Buttons to move the text are in the bottom pane. Thank you for any help.

So I know what the problem is just don't know how to fix it. When the text gets to the buttons, the gridpane in the center starts covering the buttons. Any Ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

```
class centerPane extends bottomPane {
GridPane center = new GridPane(); // Create center root pane.
private static final String MEDIA_URL = 


BorderPane video = new BorderPane(); // Pane containing MediaView and video controls.
video.setCenter(mediaView);
video.setBottom(hBox);
video.maxHeightProperty().bind(mediaView.fitHeightProperty().add(15));
// Creating pane containing text
Pane textpane = new Pane();
textpane.getChildren().add(name);
center.add(textpane, 0, 0);
center.add(video,2,0);
center.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
center.setHgap(100);
pane.setCenter(center);


btUp.setOnAction(e ->  name.setY(name.getY() - 10));
btDown.setOnAction(e -> name.setY(name.getY() + 10));



return pane;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Right now it's not clear what some of the variables and classes are (what is `name`, what is `borromPane` etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to bring the buttons to front after movement of textpane.

```
btUp.toFront();
btDown.toFront();
```